# How can I prevent repositories.config from being automatically added to TFS?

Tags: tfs, nuget

I am using NuGet v2.8.60610.756. Every time I build a solution in VS2013, packages/repositories.config is automatically added to source control (TFVC) as a pending change. How can I prevent this?

I have added a .tfignore file at the solution root with the following entries, but it does not make a difference.

```
## Ignore the NuGet packages folder in the root of the repository
packages
packages/*
```

I have also set disableSourceControlIntegration to true in .nuget/NuGet.config

```
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why would you not want to check it in? I always do...

Comment: Do you have update 5 for Visual Studio?

Comment: @MrHinsh I use the automatic package restore process new in Nuget 2.7+. The documentation (http://docs.nuget.org/Consume/Package-Restore) indicates that the entire packages folder including repositories.config is not needed. I do have update 5 for VS.